# Как сделать такое с псевдоклассом focus?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой div блок:

```
<div class="uk-navbar-right">
    <div class="search">
        <input class="search__input" type="text"  placeholder="Поиск...">
    </div>
    <div class="search__dropdown"></div>
</div>
```

На эти элементы действую такие css классы:

```
.search{
  height: 42px;
}
.search__input{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 42px 0 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    transition: .4s cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0, 1);
    width: 300px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
    transition: 0.3s all;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search__input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #1e87f0;
}
.search__input::-moz-placeholder{
    color: #1e87f0;
}
.search__input:focus {
    color: #1e87f0;
    cursor: text;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1e87f0;
}
```

Как сделать так, когда кликаешь на Input, и чтоб div.search__dropdown добавлялось свойство disply: block, а когда убирать фокус то display:none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению без скриптов не получится...

Если бы разметка была вот такая, то получится:

```css
.search__input{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 42px 0 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    transition: .4s cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0, 1);
    width: 300px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
    transition: 0.3s all;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search__input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #1e87f0;
}
.search__input::-moz-placeholder{
    color: #1e87f0;
}
.search__input:focus {
    color: #1e87f0;
    cursor: text;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1e87f0;
}



.search__dropdown {
  background: red;
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

.search__input:focus + .search__dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-navbar-right">

  <input class="search__input" type="text"  placeholder="Поиск...">

  <div class="search__dropdown"></div>
</div>
```

суть в том, что в CSS нельзя подняться на уровень выше во вложенных блоках чтобы применить стиль к элементу `.search__dropdown`

А вот если `input` и `.search__dropdown` будут на одном уровне, можно применить селектор отношения `+`, который говорит о том, что стили нужно применить к элементу, находящемуся непосредственно ПОД заданным элементом.

Comment: "+" первый правый сосед - это кроссбраузерное решение (как минимум поддержка браузерами по IE9 включительно)

Comment: первый правый сосед - работает и в IE8.